# SQL/MS Access 2010 - where with multiple conditions not returning proper values

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

```
SELECT t.COD, t.ITEM, t.FIRST, t.FINAL
FROM TabE t
WHERE t.COD = COD_P AND t.FIRST NOT IN(1) AND t.FINAL NOT IN(1000,1100)
```

"COD_P" is a Parameter given by the user.
I want to get all values that match the COD_P and the t.FIRST isn't 1 and t.FINAL isn't 1000 to 1100, but the returned values are excluding items that have t.FIRST = 1, and not caring if they have a t.FINAL = 5.

Example:
User input for COD_P = 1

In TabE, I have:

```
| COD | ITEM | FIRST | FINAL |
|   1 |   12 |     1 |  1000 |
|   1 |   12 |     1 |     2 |
|   1 |   12 |     1 |    10 |
|   1 |   12 |     1 |  1100 |
|   2 |   12 |     1 |  1000 |
|   3 |   12 |     1 |  1000 |
|   3 |   12 |     1 |  1000 |
|   4 |   12 |     1 |  1000 |
|   5 |   12 |     1 |  1000 |
```

He should return me the second and third values.

Comment: Given the above query, sample data, and input the expected result is no records are returned. Is that not what you are seeing? This is based on `AND t.FIRST NOT IN(1)` which would exclude all sample records.

Comment: `"and not caring if they have a t.FINAL = 5."` <= I see nothing about this in your original query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem #1: `IN` doesn't mean what you appear to be using it for.

To say "`t.FIRST` isn't 1" you should just use `t.FIRST <> 1` (though in this case what you did may work).

To say "`t.FINAL` isn't 1000 to 1100" you should use `t.FINAL NOT BETWEEN 1000 AND 1100`.  What you wrote would allow, for example, 1050 - which doesn't match your description of what you want.

Problem #2: the desired logic is unclear

When you talk about the incorrect result, you're implying that you only want to exclude records where FIRST is 1 *AND* FINAL is between 1000 and 1100 (because you seem to mean that FIRST=1,FINAL=5 shouldn't be excluded).  That's not what your written description says, and it's certainly not what your query logic says.  If that's what you want, you need something like

```
AND NOT (FIRST = 1 AND FINAL BETWEEN 1000 AND 1100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the conditions are not additive, i.e are not to be considered together, you would use the `or` operator:

```
SELECT t.COD, t.ITEM, t.FIRST, t.FINAL
FROM TabE t
WHERE t.COD = COD_P AND (t.FIRST NOT IN(1) OR t.FINAL NOT IN(1000,1100))
```